# postfix header check replace from without at sign

Tags: postfix, regex

I want to replace the from field if it does not contain the **@** sign:

```
if /^From:/
!/^From:.*@/ REPLACE From: no-reply@example.com
endif
```

Testing the regex looks promising:

```
postmap -q "From: foo" regexp:/etc/postfix/test
REPLACE From: no-reply@example.com
postmap -q "From: foo@" regexp:/etc/postfix/test
...
```

However if I try to postmap the file I get:

```
postmap: warning: test, line 3: expected format: key whitespace value
```

If I send an email with a valid from field the text is preserved, but not the other way around.

What am I missing here ?